# Chrome App, Angular 2 - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: angular, google-chrome-app

I have a basic "hello world" angular 2 application that I am trying to launch as a chrome **app**; however, I am  having some difficulties.

Originally, I was getting the following error:

```
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive
```

I corrected the above by enabling sandbox mode in the manifest file.

Now I am getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://cfobooeijgackndlciaclnekfkinmfpi/source/main.js. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

main.js is basically just my bootstrapper file for ng2.

I am new to chrome apps. Is there anything special I need to configure in order to allow this? I believe this is something related to CSP but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my chrome app manifest file:

```
{
  "name":  "APP", 
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "DESC",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "background",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "geolocation",
    "experimental"
  ],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [
        "source/background.js"
      ] 
    } 
  },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": [
      "source/index.html"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Note that your original problem is a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5956).

Comment: Ahh, nice find... Do you know of any work-arounds?

Comment: You mean, besides using Angular 1?

Comment: Haha, yes, using ng2.

Comment: There is one mentioned in the bug report (patching `eval` out). Personally, I don't know any.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for referencing the bug. At least I know this is something they are aware of and looking into.